# Django: how do i edit/update a model?

Tags: django

Argh. Hey all, i have a muy simple django question:

And argh, i'm sorry, i've read and read, and I am *sure* this is covered somewhere super-obviously, but i haven't found it!

How do i edit/update a model using django? Like, the data values? Not the model fields?

Here is my code! (I'm using a home-brew version of stuff!)

Here is the urls:

```
url(r'^editStory/(?P<id>\d+)$',
    StoryModelView.as_view(
        context_object_name='form',
        template_name ='stories/editStory.html',
        success_template= 'stories/editStorySuccess.html'
    ),
    {},
    'editStory'
),
```

Here is the view:

```
def get(self,request,id=None):
    form = self.getForm(request,id)
    return self.renderValidations(form)

def getForm(self, request,id):
    if id:
        return self.getModelById(request,id)
    return StoryForm()

def getModelById(self,request,id):
    theStory = get_object_or_404(Story, pk=id)
    if theStory.user != request.user:
        raise HttpResponseForbidden()
    return StoryForm(theStory)

def renderValidations(self,form):
    if self.context_object_name:
        contextName = self.context_object_name
    else:
        contextName = 'form'
    if self.template_name:
        return render_to_response(self.template_name,{contextName:form})
    else :
        return render_to_response('stories/addStory.html',{contextName:form})

def getPostForm(self,request,id):
    if id:
        theStory = self.idHelper(request,id)
        return StoryForm(request.POST,theStory)
    return StoryForm(request.POST)

def processForm(self,form,request):
    theStory = form.save(commit=False)
    theStory.user = request.user
    return theStory
```

Here is the template code:

```
{% block content %}
    <h3>Edit story</h3>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {%  csrf_token %}
        {%  for field in form %}
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

try as i might, i either:

1. get an error
2. get nothing

i get an error with the code as-displayed, caused by this line

> ```
>     {% for field in form %}
> ```

and with the error of:

```
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'Story' object has no attribute 'get'
```

or i get nothing - no data at all - if i change my "getModelById" method to read:

```
def getModelById(self,request,id):
    theStory = get_object_or_404(StoryForm, pk=id)
    if theStory.user != request.user:
        raise HttpResponseForbidden()
    return theStory
```

StoryForm is one of those "ModelForm" things, and its model is "Story".

SO! The question:

how do i fix this code to make it work? What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show what your class is inheriting from, but it seems like you're just using a standard single object display view. Instead, you should use one of the [editing mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#editing-mixins) that are provided for this purpose.

Comment: editing mixins is what everybody says so hooray for answers - although i was completely unable to find an "editing mixin for dummy's" tutorial to guide me. In the end, i made a class that extended View, and overwrote the  get and post methods to make the changes. I might post the code up later and ask "how do i convert this to a mixin"

Comment: Have another look at the generic views docs. They've just (in the last couple of days) completely revamped it so it's a lot easier to use, so it might actually be helpful now.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your model looks like, are you looking for something along the lines of

```
s = Story.objects.get(some criteria)
s.user = <some user>
s.save()
```

?

Sorry, I find your question a little vague.

Upon rereading, one thing jumped out at me:

You can't do a query (get, filter, or any variation on these) on a model-- you have to do it on an object manager, like objects.

So, as above, in your case, Story.objects.get_object_or_404 should solve your error.